# How can i create a dictionary from 2 lists with one as the key and the other as as the value with only loops? Without using zip() or enumerate()

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, data-structures

I wanna achieve this without any libraries or special functions just loops. I wanna have a main program that takes in 2 inputs which are the 2 lists and returns the dictionary like shown below.

```
Please enter the item names: Cans, bottles, boxes, jugs 

please enter quantities : 20,34,10

output : {'Cans':'20','bottles':'34','boxes':'10','jugs':'0'}
```

If the list of items is longer than the quantities then the quantity becomes automatically 0 as it did with the jugs above.

If the List of Quantity is longer than the items list then the item should automatically become 'unknown object_1' with the number changing accordingly.

Comment: Split the input on comma. Create an empty dictionary (`result={}`). Go through names using indexes (`for i in range(len(names))`), take `i`-th element from both lists (or 0 for second list) and add it to dictionary: `result[names[i]] = quantities[i]`

Comment: This looks like homework or other assignment, so I leave assembling the bits to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Split with comma as delimiter. Fill values with zero for a number of iterations equal to the difference in length between keys and values.

Then use dict comprehension to build your dict. This with the `zip` built-in function.

```
keys = 'a,b,c,d'

values = '1,2,3'

keys = keys.split(',')

values = values.split(',')

for i in range(len(keys) - len(values)):
    values.append('0')

dct = {}

for i in range(len(keys)):
    dct[keys[i]] = values[i]

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '0'}
```

This uses only built-in calls so it fits your requirements at best. At the OP requirements it is not using the zip function.

Comment: `{k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}` can also be written `dict(zip(keys, values))`

Comment: Without using zip or enumerate !

Comment: @Xflo zip is built-in it is like a for loop purely standard. But still, I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = list(input().split(','))
b = list(map(int, input().split(',')))

res = {}

for i in range(len(a)):
    res[a[i]] = b[i] if i < len(b) else 0
print(res)
```

Comment: OPs input is separated by `,`. Please add this to your `split` functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
item_names = ['Cans', 'Bottles', 'boxes', 'jugs']
quantities = [20, 34, 10]
output_dict = {}

for i, item in enumerate(item_names):
    if i > len(quantities) - 1:
         output_dict.update({item : 0})
    else:
         output_dict.update({item : quantities[i]})
```

Comment: You can write directly `output_dict[item] = quantities[i]` instead of `output_dict.update({item : quantities[i]})`

Comment: Without using zip or enumerate !

Comment: Yes that is correct Stef, this is what I first did, but had a strange bug, so I used the update method.
When you don't want to use enumerate, you can just add another variable and count this up in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['cans','Bottles','Boxes','Jugs']
list2 = [1,2,3]

res = {}

for i, element in enumerate(list1):
    try:
        res[element] = list2[i]
    except IndexError:
        res[element] = 0
        
print(res)
```

Edited code without enumerate or zip:

````
list1 = ['cans','Bottles','Boxes','Jugs']
list2 = [1,2,3]

res = {}
i=0
for element in list1:
    try:
        res[element] = list2[i]
    except IndexError:
        res[element] = 0
    i+=1
        
print(res)
    ```
````

Comment: Without using zip or enumerate !